# Visual Studio 2019 - VSIX/C# - custom window displaying class name instead of class content

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I try to display a custom window in my VSIX extension

I launch it from the main AsyncPackage

```
protected override async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, 
IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
{
    ...
    ShowHintWindow();
}

private void ShowHintWindow()
{
    var hintWindow = new MyNameSpace.hintWindow.hintWindow();
    var window = new System.Windows.Window
    {
        Content = hintWindow,
        Title = "Hint",
        SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight
    };

    window.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
    window.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;

    window.Show();
}
```

The goal is to display some hint with a close button

But as the VSIX starts, it only shows the hintWindow class as content

The following xaml is not injected in the window:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNameSpace.hintWindow.hintWindowControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:vsshell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0"
             Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowKey}}"
             Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowTextKey}}"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             IsVisibleChanged="MyToolWindow_IsVisibleChanged"
             Name="MyToolWindow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Keyboard.KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown">
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <TextBlock Text="Notification" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MainText}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="Ok" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                <Button Content="Don't show again" Width="150" Height="30" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

hintWindow class :

```
public class hintWindow : ToolWindowPane
{
   public hintWindow() : base(null)
   {
      this.Caption = "HintWindow Search";
      this.Content = new hintWindowControl(this);
   }
}
```

am I missing something ?

thanks for your help

Comment: anyone ? I updated my question

Comment: nobody ????????

Comment: trying to directly using  hintwinowcontrol in showhintwindow method:        var hintWindowControl = new MyNameSpace.hintWindow.hintWindowControl();
       var window = new System.Windows.Window
       {
           Content = hintWindowControl,
           // ... other window properties ...
       };

       window.Show();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a toolwindow, you should be invoking ShowToolWindowAsync, rather than using WPF APIs to display the window.

It looks like you already added a toolwindow to the VSIX package, that will add a menu command handler that shows the toolwindow, something like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Shows the tool window when the menu item is clicked.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The event sender.</param>
/// <param name="e">The event args.</param>
private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.package.JoinableTaskFactory.RunAsync(async delegate
    {
        ToolWindowPane window = await this.package.ShowToolWindowAsync(typeof(ToolWindow1), 0, true, this.package.DisposalToken);
        if ((null == window) || (null == window.Frame))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot create tool window");
        }
    });
}
```